# Printing double quotes of unnamed list with toJSON

Tags: r, double-quotes, jsonlite

I have json data that I'm importing to R and then exporting in the exact same format. The original code looks like:

> "Entries":{**""**:11.8988438}

Using `names<-("")`, I can reproduce the double quotes in R, but when writing with `write_json(x)`, I've only come up with:

> "Entries":{11.8988438}
>   or
>   "Entries":{"1":11.8988438}
>   or

I've tried manipulating the print options, and no luck so far. I'd be grateful for any other ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete JSON file for testing:

```
{"Entries":{"":11.8988438}}
```

If I read and write using `package:rjson` I get empty-named entities:

```
> r = rjson::fromJSON(file="./foo.json")
> r
$Entries
$Entries[[1]]
[1] 11.89884


> rjson::toJSON(r)
[1] "{\"Entries\":{\"\":11.8988438}}"
```

So use the `rjson` package?